# How to upgrade python3-venv to 3.9 version in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: upgrade, python3, virtualenv

I need to install tensorflow which requires python version > 3.7 because of which I had to upgrade the python version in ubuntu 18.04 from 3.6 to 3.9. I upgraded to python 3.9 using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
Then select 2
```

Then I installed python3-venv corresponding to version 3.9. I do it using:

```
 sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev python3.9-venv
```

Now I create a virtual environment using

```
python3.9 -m venv dl4cv
```

**My question is: Will the created dl4cv correspond to the python version 3.9 or 3.6? Also is this process to create the virtual environment in the updated 3.9 version correct?**

Comment: That ought to work. Have you tried running the command you posted above? To verify the version, you could then run `dl4cv/bin/python --version`. If it shows `Python 3.9.X` then you are all set.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python3.9-dev
E: Unable to locate package python3.9-venv